# Unaligned dots in Table Of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, appendices

I have this code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage[title,titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\titlerule*{.}}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecleader}{\titlerule*{.}}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsubsecleader}{\titlerule*{.}}
\renewcommand{\appendixname}{}
\renewcommand{\appendixtocname}{Anhang}
\renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\tableofcontents
\section{Foo}
\subsection{Foo1}
\subsection{Foo2}
\section{Bar}
\subsection{Bar1}
\subsection{Bar2}
\apptocmd{\appendices}{\apptocmd{\thesection}{: }{}{}}{}{}
\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{1\baselineskip}}
\titlecontents{section}{\underline{\appendixtocname\,\thecontentslabel :}\quad}{}{}{\titlerule*{.}\thecontentspage}{}
\titleformat{\section}{\bfseries\large}{Anhang \thesection:\,}{}{}

\begin{appendices}
\appendix
\section{App1}
\section{App2}
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

It looks like this:
[image: This image]

It looks bad, there are at least three or four missing dots and the distance between the dots and the page number is shorter, too. How can I make this look better, so the page numbers and the end of the dots are aligned?

Comment: Are you writing in German? If so, have you considered the KOMA Script classes?

Comment: No, I didn't know about KOMA

Comment: It's a lot like the standard classes, with many of the defaults set to European typographic conventions. Documentation can be a bit sparse, and is primarily in German, but when it works, it works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really should be a comment, but the formatting warrants I post this as an “answer”. Take a look at this example:

```
\documentclass[listof=totoc,toc=sectionentrywithdots]{scrartcl}

\begin{document} 

\tableofcontents 
\cleardoublepage

\section{Chapter Number One}
\clearpage

\section{Chapter Number Two}
\clearpage

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\underline{Anhang A:}\quad FOO} 
\section*{\underline{Anhang A:}\quad FOO}
\clearpage

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\underline{Anhang A:}\quad BAR} 
\section*{\underline{Anhang B:}\quad BAR}
\clearpage

\end{document}
```

Does this come close to what you're looking for? (The `\clearpage` commands are only necessary because there's no real text and there are no enforced new pages for an article.)

Comment: Nearly. The appendices should be like `\underline{Anhang A:}\quad $NAME_OF_APPENDIX`

Comment: I'm sure you'll figure it out :-)

Comment: Thanks! It worked. I reached what I wanted